# Closed form of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\ln(n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form of this :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\ln(n),$$
 where $|x|<1$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53628/the-identity-sum-n-lnn-xn-sum-p-lnp-sum-k-fracxpk1-xpk/ is what you need.
Hope it helps out.

Answer (score 2):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^a}=\text{Li}_a(x)$. Now, differentiate both sides with regard to *a*, and then let $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It admits a very simple approximation using Euler-Maclaurin formula:
$$
I_k = \int_{1}^{\infty}x^k \log x dx = -\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\Bigg|_{1}^{\infty}- \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}dx}{k+1} = O\bigg(\frac{1}{k^2}\bigg)
$$
This is since $\lim_{m \to 1} \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2}(f(n)-f(m))=0$